# Exception: The XPath expression evaluated to unexpected type System.Xml.Linq.XText

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm trying to get a value from Xml by using xpath. example xml:

```
 <Wetter>
    <Tabelle>
        <internalID>38</internalID>
        <Name>Algier</Name>
        <Tag>Donnerstag</Tag>
        <Datum>29.11.18</Datum>
        <Symbol>heiter.gif</Symbol>
        <deutsch>heiter</deutsch>
        <englisch>partly cloudy</englisch>
        <franzoesisch>Peu nuageux / Quelques nuages</franzoesisch>
        <italienisch>poco nuvoloso</italienisch>
        <spanisch>Parcialmente nuboso</spanisch>
        <portugiesisch>Parcialmente enublado</portugiesisch>
        <Tmin>14</Tmin>
        <Tmax>22</Tmax>
        <TminF>57</TminF>
        <TmaxF>72</TmaxF>
        <Regenwk>0</Regenwk>
        <WindRi>N</WindRi>
        <WindBft>2</WindBft>
    </Tabelle>
</Wetter>
```

Whole xml is packet into the XDocument object, and I'm trying to access "Datum" field of "Tabelle" node, based on the "Name" value in this node:

```
FormattableString xpath = $"/Wetter/Tabelle[Name = '{name}'][1]/Datum/text()";
var date = weatherXml.XPathSelectElement(xpath.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
return date.Value;
```

I've tested this xpath in various testers, and it seems to be ok, however when executing the code, it gives this exception:

```
The XPath expression evaluated to unexpected type System.Xml.Linq.XText
```

I've also tried changing XPathSelectElement to XpathEvaluate based on other stack questions, but then I get null as a result.

Comment: recommend using deserialization to object/class instead...

Comment: If you remove the `/text()` so that the select returns the `<Date>` element instead of its text, it should work.

Comment: @JohnB Ye, thats also a way, but I wanted to use XPath in order to learn it a bit.

Comment: @KlausGütter Worked just fine, thanks mate. Can you maybe describe it to me why it worked in xpath testers, and c# gave this error?

Comment: The XPath is fine, but it does not return an Element as XPathSelectElement requires but a text node. See also my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `/text()` so that the select returns the `<Date>` element instead of its text, it should work.
Alternatively use `XPathEvaluate` instead of `XPathSelectElement`.